# Android gradle build failed with Nullpointer Exception

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I am trying to build a Android project in CentOS machine as part of Continuous Integration.
Dev team builds in Windows and it works fine in their machine.

In CentOS machine, I am seeing below error. Any idea what is going wrong. Below is the stacktrace.
I have set proxy info in gradle.properties.
I have setup Android build tools and platform tools.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.updateRepositories(DefaultSdkLoader.java:455)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.collectArtifacts(DependencyManager.java:550)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.gatherDependencies(DependencyManager.java:385)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencyForConfig(DependencyManager.java:288)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:159)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.resolveDependencies(TaskManager.java:364)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$9.call(VariantManager.java:636)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$9.call(VariantManager.java:633)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.java:44)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantData(VariantManager.java:629)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantDataForProductFlavors(VariantManager.java:823)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.populateVariantDataList(VariantManager.java:494)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$1.call(VariantManager.java:269)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$1.call(VariantManager.java:266)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:265)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:688)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:685)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:683)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
        ... 56 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Build.gradle of app module.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "au.com.company.appname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //added library for decoding
    //read more functionality library
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    compile 'at.blogc:expandabletextview:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.10.0'
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-common:1.10.0'
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-commonwidget:1.10.0'
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:1.10.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Update 1**

I followed this link [Android build fails due to Proxy](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/218) and created gradle.properties in $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-25

Now I am getting this error.

```
Preparing "Install SDK Patch Applier v4".
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package SDK Patch Applier v4: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required".:
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2124)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:245)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openDirectUrl(DownloadCache.java:338)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.LegacyDownloader.downloadFully(LegacyDownloader.java:79)
        at com.android.repository.impl.downloader.LocalFileAwareDownloader.downloadFully(LocalFileAwareDownloader.java:81)
        at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:71)
        at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:243)
        at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installRemotePackages(DefaultSdkLoader.java:325)
        at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.updateRepositories(DefaultSdkLoader.java:458)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.collectArtifacts(DependencyManager.java:550)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.gatherDependencies(DependencyManager.java:385)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencyForConfig(DependencyManager.java:288)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:159)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.resolveDependencies(TaskManager.java:364)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$9.call(VariantManager.java:636)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$9.call(VariantManager.java:633)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.java:44)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantData(VariantManager.java:629)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantDataForProductFlavors(VariantManager.java:823)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.populateVariantDataList(VariantManager.java:494)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$1.call(VariantManager.java:269)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$1.call(VariantManager.java:266)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:265)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:688)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$11.call(BasePlugin.java:685)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:683)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
"Install SDK Patch Applier v4" failed.


* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
  [Android Support Repository, Google Repository]
  Please install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
```

Comment: https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/165 check this

Comment: can you show your build of app module

Comment: I have added in the original post as its content is too long to add as comment.

Comment: `DefaultSdkLoader.updateRepositories`... What repositories are you using? Your proxy could be blocking it

Comment: The project build.gradle uses only one repository. I tried building in Windows. Build is working fine fyi.       
`buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }`

Comment: @cricket_007 : Can you check my Update 1. Now 407 (Proxy Authentication Required")  is being displayed.

Comment: I have never used a proxy, but that is apparently your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from update 1 on original post,I downloaded "Android Support Repository and Google Repository" using below commands and now build is working fine.

```
/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --no_https --proxy=http --proxy_host=127.0.0.1 --proxy_port=3128 "extras;google;m2repository"

/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --no_https --proxy=http --proxy_host=127.0.0.1 --proxy_port=3128 "extras;android;m2repository"
```

Although this is good for timebeing, I will be interested to hear if someone can point out how can we set proxy, so that packages will automatically get downloaded during build.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Comment: Is there any info how can you pass proxy authenticatino setup for sdkmanager?