# Android Build with Gradle(Behind Proxy) failing

Tags: android, macos, proxy, ntlm, gradlew

This question is similar to this [Android build issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337466/android-gradle-build-failed-with-nullpointer-exception?noredirect=1#comment79674532_46337466)

I am setting up CI for Android build in a Mac mini(10.12).

We have a corp proxy and that is the reason causing all these issues I think.
First I tried setting proxy info in ~/.bash_profile.

Then I set up cntlm and tried to build Android project.
ANDROID_HOME is set to /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk

I got this error

```
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Failed to download any source lists!

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Next I ran ./gradlew build --info and got below output

```
Initialized native services in: /Users/jenkins/.gradle/native
Connected to daemon DaemonInfo{pid=6465, address=[3646567b-c480-4beb-a6d2-2ba0120d1cd8 port:54872, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1506668208517, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=6c85c027-6030-4dfe-91b8-6a40166e80af,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/jenkins/.gradle/daemon,pid=6465,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=AU,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}. Dispatching request Build{id=f5180918-cde6-414f-8694-c8777c5c6d05.1, currentDir=/Users/jenkins/home/ws/tankstream-android/tankstreamandroid}.
Received result org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted@2d6c53fc from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=6465, address=[3646567b-c480-4beb-a6d2-2ba0120d1cd8 port:54872, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1506668208517, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=6c85c027-6030-4dfe-91b8-6a40166e80af,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/jenkins/.gradle/daemon,pid=6465,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=AU,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be starting).
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 6465). The daemon log file: /Users/jenkins/.gradle/daemon/3.3/daemon-6465.out.log
Starting 9th build in daemon [uptime: 28 mins 20.507 secs, performance: 100%, no major garbage collections]
Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=6c85c027-6030-4dfe-91b8-6a40166e80af,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/jenkins/.gradle/daemon,pid=6465,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=AU,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Creating new cache for plugin-use-metadata, path /Users/jenkins/.gradle/caches/3.3/plugin-resolution/plugin-use-metadata.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@20ff28b
Creating new cache for client-status, path /Users/jenkins/.gradle/caches/3.3/plugin-resolution/client-status.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@20ff28b
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/Users/jenkins/home/ws/tankstream-android/tankstreamandroid/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/Users/jenkins/home/ws/tankstream-android/tankstreamandroid/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'tankstreamandroid', project ':app']
Evaluating root project 'tankstreamandroid' using build file '/Users/jenkins/home/ws/tankstream-android/tankstreamandroid/build.gradle'.
Creating new cache for metadata-2.23/module-metadata, path /Users/jenkins/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/module-metadata.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@1a84b028
Creating new cache for metadata-2.23/artifact-at-repository, path /Users/jenkins/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/artifact-at-repository.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@1a84b028
Evaluating project ':app' using build file '/Users/jenkins/home/ws/tankstream-android/tankstreamandroid/app/build.gradle'.
Using 4 worker leases.
Creating configuration compile
Creating configuration apk
Creating configuration provided
Creating configuration wearApp
Creating configuration annotationProcessor
Creating configuration jackPlugin
Creating configuration androidTestCompile
Creating configuration androidTestApk
Creating configuration androidTestProvided
Creating configuration androidTestWearApp
Creating configuration androidTestAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration androidTestJackPlugin
Creating configuration testCompile
Creating configuration testApk
Creating configuration testProvided
Creating configuration testWearApp
Creating configuration testAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration testJackPlugin
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Creating configuration debugCompile
Creating configuration debugApk
Creating configuration debugProvided
Creating configuration debugWearApp
Creating configuration debugAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration debugJackPlugin
Creating configuration testDebugCompile
Creating configuration testDebugApk
Creating configuration testDebugProvided
Creating configuration testDebugWearApp
Creating configuration testDebugAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration testDebugJackPlugin
Creating configuration releaseCompile
Creating configuration releaseApk
Creating configuration releaseProvided
Creating configuration releaseWearApp
Creating configuration releaseAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration releaseJackPlugin
Creating configuration testReleaseCompile
Creating configuration testReleaseApk
Creating configuration testReleaseProvided
Creating configuration testReleaseWearApp
Creating configuration testReleaseAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration testReleaseJackPlugin
Parsing the SDK, no caching allowed
SDK initialized in 3 ms
Creating new cache for metadata-2.23/artifact-at-url, path /Users/jenkins/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/artifact-at-url.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@1a84b028
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.2/constraint-layout-1.0.2.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.2/constraint-layout-1.0.2.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/25.3.1/design-25.3.1.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/25.3.1/design-25.3.1.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/25.3.1/support-v4-25.3.1.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/25.3.1/support-v4-25.3.1.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.0.1/play-services-maps-11.0.1.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/11.0.1/play-services-maps-11.0.1.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.0.1/play-services-location-11.0.1.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.0.1/play-services-location-11.0.1.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/11.0.1/play-services-plus-11.0.1.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/11.0.1/play-services-plus-11.0.1.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/11.0.1/play-services-analytics-11.0.1.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/11.0.1/play-services-analytics-11.0.1.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/23.4.0/customtabs-23.4.0.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/23.4.0/customtabs-23.4.0.jar]
Creating new cache for metadata-2.23/module-artifacts, path /Users/jenkins/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/module-artifacts.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@1a84b028
Parsing /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/package.xml
Parsing /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/package.xml
Parsing /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/package.xml
Parsing /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/emulator/package.xml
Parsing /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/patcher/v4/package.xml
Parsing /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/platform-tools/package.xml
Parsing /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/platforms/android-25/package.xml
Parsing /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/platforms/android-26/package.xml
Parsing /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/tools/package.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Failed to download any source lists!

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.186 secs
Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=6465, address=[3646567b-c480-4beb-a6d2-2ba0120d1cd8 port:54872, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1506668208517, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=6c85c027-6030-4dfe-91b8-6a40166e80af,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/jenkins/.gradle/daemon,pid=6465,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=AU,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
```

I tried putting gradle.properties in ~/.gradle/ and in /Users/jenkins/home/android-sdk/platforms/

Any idea what can be done?

**Note :** Same project works fine from android Studio in a windows machine and in linux machine( after I downloaded google repository)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone ? I am still facing this issue and no luck so far. 
I am surprised why the configured cntlm proxy setting is not being taken by android build tools. 
CNTLM is set correctly and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue was in the build.gradle file.
Apparently we need to use multiple repositories for Windows / Linux / Mac.

1) While building in windows, 
repositories from `http://jcenter.bintray.com/` is enough.

But while doing Android build on Mac / Linux, we need `https://maven.google.com`

Hence I added

```
  maven {
             url 'https://maven.google.com'
         }
```

and my final build.gradle looks like below.

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
        maven {
             url 'https://maven.google.com'
         }
    }
}
```

Now builds are happening on Windows / Linux / Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Check `app/build.gradle` to find the required Build Tools version used by the project. For example:

```
android {
    ...
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    ...
}
```

Now go to Android Studio > SDK Tools > Select "Show Package Details".

Find the Build Tools version you need under Android SDK Build-Tools. Select that version and click OK to install it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting the same error but it was because Build Tools version was not recognized in the Intranet.

Changing it to the latest tools version number fixed the problem:

[Check latest SDK Build tools versions](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)